# struct with a array pointer printing "random numbers" in the print_stack() function

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I was training and studying the structures that are used in C, but when I was trying to create a data structure I got an issue, like that it was printing, random numbers. I think that he was printing the address of any array element in this pointer of array, but I want to know how do I fix it to make a print the value by a pointer pointing to an array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//creating a struct for a data structure

typedef struct {
    int size;
    int (*Arr)[10];
    int top;
} Stack;

//function prototype
void print_Stack(Stack *pilha);

int main() {
    Stack pilha;
    int Elementos[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    
    pilha.Arr = &Elementos;
    pilha.size = sizeof(Elementos) / sizeof(int);

    print_Stack(&pilha);
    return 0;
}

//creating a print stack function
void print_Stack(Stack *pilha) {
    for (int x = 0; x < pilha->size; x++) {
        printf("%d", pilha->Arr[x]);
    }
}
```

I know that has a better way to create a array in struct, anyway, I want a solution for how I print the values in a pointer array to use it in another situations, if you explain it, it turns better :), because I am beginner in programming, and I like to learn it in hard way.

I was trying to make the get the address, put on variable, and the make the `*` again to get the value but it doesn't work.

Comment: In `int (*Arr)[10];` you have a double indexing: once for `[10]` and once more for the `*`... so to get to the values you need two dereferences: `printf("%d",pilha->Arr[0][x]);` or `printf("%d",(*pilha->Arr)[x]);`

Comment: Not sure what the point of `size` is, when it's hard-coded into the program. Which... avoid magic numbers.

Comment: Check this out: https://ideone.com/ga4SLr

Comment: Which works because `arr[0]` is equivalent to `*(arr + 0)` which is equivalent to `*arr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pilha->Arr` is a pointer to an `int[10]` so you need to dereference it (with `*`) when printing the values in the array:

```c
printf("%d", (*pilha->Arr)[x]);
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Another option would be to make `Arr` an `int*` instead:

```c
#include <stddef.h>  // size_t
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ARRSIZE(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    int *Arr;                               // int*
    int top;
} Stack;

void print_Stack(Stack *pilha) {
    for (size_t x = 0; x < pilha->size; x++) {
        printf("%d", pilha->Arr[x]);        // now this works
    }
}

int main() {
    Stack pilha;
    int Elementos[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    pilha.Arr = Elementos;                  // and you assign it like this
    pilha.size = ARRSIZE(Elementos);

    print_Stack(&pilha);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna test it later because i'm not with the pc but thanks for guide the of the problem :)

Comment: @KalebSUS You're welcome! Hope it works out!